# is it possible in jquery to create an event listener for display change of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a wizard , each step is a `div` with it's own id `{step-1,step-2,...}`
navigation happens by changing display of steps.
from step-1 to step-2 :

```
step-1 -> display="none" and 
step-2 -> display="block"
```

Now I want an event to listen to display of `step-2`, when it changed to block call some functions.
Thanks

Comment: You would probably be better off creating a notification step in your code rather than trying to watch the visibility of some item on screen as a signal that the code has done something.  So, have your code create a custom event and fire that event when a step is changed.  Then you can have as many application listeners for a new step as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Modern browsers support the use of [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). After an object is added to the observer using the `.observe()` method, a callback will be triggered when that object's attributes change. The callback will recieve a [Mutation Record](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationRecord) detailing the old and new attributes.

(Note this does not involve any JQuery).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if`. If `#step-2` is currently `display:none` , we need to change it to block first, and then do some thing.

```
$('#next').click(function(){
 if($('#step-2').css('display') == 'none'){
     $('#step-2').css({
         'display' : 'block'
     });
//do some thing after #step-2 display block
}else{
//do some thing else
}
});
```

Or

```
$('#next').click(function(){
     if($('#step-2').is(':visible'){
     //do some thing
}
});
```

It's not a good approach but i think it will do the trick

Comment: it is good but I really want an event listener not on a click method

Answer (score 0):

I did it  with your helps. but I fount smartwizard .
I used it.
https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard